# Server, which wil kill and again run the infinite loop

Tags: python, loops, server

I need to create simple server, which will run some kind of infite loop, for example:

```
try:
  while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("I'm Running",time.clock())
```

I need server to kill the loop after sometime and then run it again, and everything until i interupt it. Can you help me please? Probably will use subprocess

Comment: A server? why not using bottle / Flask ?

Comment: If you want it to end at some time, it's not infinite!  Can't you just make a program that runs an infinite loop and use your operating system to start and stop that service.

Comment: Actually, my boss need it to test subprocess, but I dont know how to do it. Yeah, it's not infinite, but i need it to run until i interrupt it. After interrupt I need it to rerun and go on. I really dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
import time

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("I'm Running",time.clock())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Don't stop me now! I'm having such a good time...")
        time.sleep(x) # instead of x put the number of
                      # seconds you want before it will start again
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, you saved my day. Thank you @nutmeg64